# I failed to send FDZ token about 20 times, what happen?

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20

I'm trying to send my FDZ token to my Exchange wallet, but no luck. I tried to increase the GAS, change the target address, process in an other time... 
But everything were failed, still paid all gas price ($0.3 to $1.4$) but the token could not be sent.
Could you please take a look at my transaction history and let me know if you see what's wrong with it:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b1fb9f9d548789b3622ec8d74cf27f0d2380d23

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, the tokens are fully released for your wallet on "**1551398400**" which translates to **UTC: Friday, 1 March 2019 00:00:00**

However looking at the canTransferIfLocked() method we can find out that if we subtract the values returned by

```
balanceOf()      -> 17633630000000000000000
getMinimumAmount -> 11129668284211733749468
result           ->  6503961715788267021000
```

We end up with the amount of tokens you can transfer today.

```
 which translates to about 6503 of your 17633
```

The **getMinimumAmount** method is labeled quite badly and actually returns the number of tokens which are currently locked to your wallet ( not transferrable before the release date passes ).

If you want to make sure you CAN send the tokens to an address just use the **Read Contract** tab on etherscan and input your wallet address and the value in the **canTransferIfLocked** field.

If it returns true, then the transaction should be successful.

https://etherscan.io/token/0x23352036e911a22cfc692b5e2e196692658aded9?a=0x5b1fb9f9d548789b3622ec8d74cf27f0d2380d23#readContract

Off-topic: 
In the future you should read the release schedule attached to an ico you participate in.. or get someone to check the code before you throw eth at it.